# iOS, APNS, Push Notification, DeviceToken,iPhone

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We are registerting our iOS application for APNS. After that APNS provide a deviceToken. Is there any process to get the iOS device registration URL on APNS.

Comment: What do you mean with `iOS device registration URL on APNS`? You only need to the token to send Push notification to the device.

Comment: Yes, You are right. But after get device token. Is there any way to get the app registration URL on APNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think No. You need your own server where you will put notification logic.

Comment: Yes,you are right. We need an intermediate server for communication between iOS device and APNS with the help of device token.